# Root spaces for a Cartan subalgebra of $\frak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

I'm having trouble computing this. If I take the Cartan subalgebra generated by
$$\left(\begin{matrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{matrix}\right)$$
then which are the two eigenspaces for the nonzero roots?

Comment: Isn't the Cartan subalgebra of $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ generated by $\left( \begin{array}{cc} 1&0\\0&-1 \end{array} \right)$?

Comment: Yes it is generated by h.

Answer (score 2):

In $\mathfrak{sl}(2)$ the diagonal matrices of trace zero form a Cartan subalgebra, but also the matrices
$$
H=\left\{\begin{pmatrix} a & b \cr -b & a \end{pmatrix} \mid a,b \in \mathbb{C}\right\}.
$$
Over the complex numbers all Cartan subalgebras are conjugated, so we may take the diagonal matrices for considering eigenspaces.

Comment: I can not see why matrices of the form in $H$ also form a CSA of $\mathfrak{sl}(2)$? (additional to matrices of the
$$
\tilde{H}=\left\{\begin{pmatrix} a & 0 \cr 0 & -a \end{pmatrix} \mid a \in \mathbb{C}\right\}.
$$
Can you give more information? Thanks.

Comment: @Ameyah This depends on the context, i.e., which definition of Cartan subalgebras is used. Such  a matrix is a regular element if and only if its determinant is nonzero, by computing the characteristic polynomial. For a regular element $h$, the generated subalgebra is self-normalizing and nilpotent, hence a Cartan subalgebra.